# JSF + Primefaces: Problem with "rendered" components with ajax

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

**EDIT**
Cant seem to get `rendered` to work correctly with `update` attributes. Here is my codes

```
        <ui:define name="left">
            <h:form>
                <p:commandLink value="Hey"
                actionListener="#{bean.setRenderComment}"
                update="comment"/>
            </h:form>
       </ui:define>
       <ui:define name="right">
            <h:panelGroup id="comment" rendered="#{bean.renderComment}">
                hello
            </h:panelGroup>
       </ui:define>
```

`renderComment` is a boolean attributes inside `bean`. `setRenderComment` basically toggle the state of `renderComment` like this

```
this.renderComment = !this.renderComment;
```

Right, every time I click on the link `Hey`, I need to refresh to either render `hello` on or off. How can I fix it, so that I dont need to refresh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not using Primefaces but Richfaces on my projects. So I am not really aware on how the refresh process is done by Primefaces. However, I have an idea that can be tested easily.

Your problem *may* be due to the fact that the component to re-render (i.e. *update*) is  not found on the HTML page. If your `rendered` attribute is equals to `false`, then the `<SPAN>` with `comment` id is **not** integrated in the HTML page generated. Thus, when the Ajax request is received on the client side, the Ajax engine is not able to refresh this `<SPAN>` as it is not found.

So what you can do is to always render your `panelGroup` and move your `rendered` attribute to a nested `<h:outputText>` that contains the *Hello* message.

Here is what I am suggesting:

```
<h:panelGroup id="comment">
    <h:outputText value="Hello" rendered="#{bean.renderComment}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This way, the panelGroup will always be refreshed after the Ajax call, and it will contain the *Hello* message or not, regarding the value of the `renderComment` attribute of your bean.

Comment: Thank you. It works :). I reason why I use `panelGroup` is because, I have many component that I want to `render` on or off using just one `rendered` attributes. If I have to do this, I guess, I might as well just take the `panelGroup` out. Thanks a lot man :D

Answer (score 1):

Since the component with the ID `comment` isn't one of the form's (an `UINamingContainer` component) children, you need to prefix the ID with `:` to instruct JSF to scan from the "upper level".

This should do:

```
<p:commandLink value="Hey"
    actionListener="#{bean.setRenderComment}"
    update=":comment" />
```

Comment: Ohh wow. I did not know that `update` only work on the same level. What if I have multiple levels. I try `::comment`, but it does not work. Can u take a look at my updated post, please?

Comment: @Harry: romaintaz has nailed it down.